# How to use odeint to differential ode solution

Tags: python, scipy

I am using odeint to solve differential equations in python and I want to calculate the derivative of ode solution. In MATLAB, the derivative of ode solution can be calculated as follows:

```
ode_fcn = @(t,y) ...;                                       % ODE Function
[t,y] = ode15i(ode_fcn, ...);                               % Integrate ODE
dy = ode_fcn(t,y);                                          % Calculate Derivatives
```

However, in python, I tried to use ode function I defined in this way, which leads to wrong answer. For example, I defined dmdT function as below:

```
dmdT(m, T, *parameters):
    pass
return [dm1dT, dm2dT, ...]
```

and then I solved the ode function

```
ode_solution = odeint(dmdT, m0, T_span, args=parameters)
```

I expect to calculate the derivative of ode_solution as follows:

```
derivative = dmdT(ode_solution, T_span, *parameters)
```

But this could be wrong sometimes, and I don't know why.

So My question is: Can I use ode function I defined to calculate the derivative of ode solution as MATLAB does?

An alternative way is to use diff function in Numpy, but it will shorten the length of data by 1. So I defined a new diff function with mid difference method which is different from the diff in Numpy to solve this problem. But this method is not elegant enough as in MATLAB.

The diff function I defined is as follows:

```
def diff(x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    # Forward difference
    dydx_start = (y[1]-y[0])/(x[1]-x[0])
    # Central difference quotient
    dydx = np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)
    dydx_mid = (dydx[1:] + dydx[:-1])/2
    # Backward difference
    dydx_end = (y[-1]-y[-2])/(x[-1]-x[-2])    
    dydx_mid = np.append(dydx_start, dydx_mid)
    return np.append(dydx_mid, dydx_end)
```

Any suggestions could be helpful, thanks a lot!

---

According to Warren Weckesser's suggestion, I tried to illustrate the problem I mentioned. Here is the code I used

```
def dmdT(m, T, beta, A1, E1, n1, k1, A2, E2, n2, k2):
    R = 8.314
    """
    FR -> char + volitale
    Polyester -> char + volitale
    """
    if len(m) == 4:
        m_FR= m[0]
        m_Polyester = m[1]
        m_residue = m[2]
        m_total = m[3]    

    
        rxn1 = -m[0]*A1 * np.exp(-E1/R/T) * (m_FR/m[0])**n1 / beta
        rxn2 = -m[1]*A2 * np.exp(-E2/R/T) * (m_Polyester/m[1])**n2 / beta
    else:
        m_FR= m[:, 0]
        m_Polyester = m[:, 1]
        m_residue = m[:, 2]  
        m_total = m[:, 3]
        
        rxn1 = -m[0,0] * A1 * np.exp(-E1/R/T) * (m_FR/m[0,0])**n1 / beta 
        rxn2 = -m[0,1] * A2 * np.exp(-E2/R/T) * (m_Polyester/m[0,1])**n2 / beta 
    
    r1 = rxn1
    r2 = rxn2
    r3 = -k1 * rxn1 - k2 * rxn2

    
    dm_FRdT = r1
    dm_PolyesterdT = r2
    dm_residuedT = r3
    dm_totalT = r1 + r2 + r3 
    
    return [dm_FRdT,  dm_PolyesterdT, dm_residuedT, dm_totalT]    

m0 = [0.0954577747, 0.9045422253, 0, 1]
T = np.arange(300, 1000, 0.1)
parameters = [5, 9.42351217e+04, 5.08266345e+04, 9.87252218e-01,
       6.90982451e-01, 8.28675597e+16, 2.29312948e+05, 6.94773512e-01,
       4.00782605e-01]
ode_solution = odeint(dmdT, m0, T, args = tuple(parameters))

MLR = dmdT(ode_solution, T, *parameters)[-1]
MLR2 = diff(T, ode_solution[:, -1])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(T, MLR)
plt.plot(T, MLR2)
```

The solutions of those two methods were different. When I use dmdT to get derivative, the warning present：

```
__main__:22: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
__main__:23: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

So I want to know why it happened and how to fix this problem? Is the odeint give wrong answer?

Thank you!

Comment: *"But this could be wrong sometimes, ..."*  How is it wrong?  Show exactly what you did, and explain why you concluded that it was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've already added the details of wrong solution